# Create lists in for loop using elements of a list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, data-transform

I have some txt files that I need to breakdown in lists

This is an example of my data.txt file inside the project:

```
2023-07-01 00:05:12#11111111111#0101107200#0055013565#3#724020
2023-07-01 00:23:15#22222222222#0101108700#0099000002#0#724020
2023-07-01 00:26:57#33333333333#0101062000#0099000029#0#724020
2023-07-01 01:33:31#44444444444#0101107100#0055013566#3#724020
2023-07-01 01:37:15#55555555555#0101107100#0055013566#3#724020
```

I need to code a program where I can get the following output:

`List1 = ['2023-07-01 00:26:57', '11111111111', '0101062000', '0099000029', '0', '724020'] List2 = ['2023-07-01 00:23:15', '22222222222', '0101062000', '0099000029', '0', '724020']`
etc lists go on...

But I am having some issues, I am not experienced with python, and that's the only(powerful) language that I can use in the server of our team(we only use bash other than python...)

I know I can get a list by splitting the content like this:

```
List = open("data.txt").readlines() 
print(List[0])
lista1 =List[0].split("#")
print(lista1)
```

But the main issue is that I have over 4000 different records in my txt file, I know in C and bash you can do something like:

```
for i in range(4000)
    lista{i} = List{[i]}.split("#")
```

In that way I could create 4000 different lists with the 4000 elemens of my current list, but it seems like python syntax doesn't support using {i}? Maybe I will have to code this in bash since C is out of the question.

TLDR: I TRIED

```
List = open("data.txt").readlines()
print(List[0])
lista1 =List[0].split("#")
print(lista1)

for i in range(4000)
    lista{i} = List{[i]}.split("#")
    print(lista{i})
```

and expected:

`List1 = ['2023-07-01 00:26:57', '11111111111', '0101062000', '0099000029', '0', '724020'] List2 = ['2023-07-01 00:23:15', '22222222222', '0101062000', '0099000029', '0', '724020']`

Comment: Use Pandas? It'll do this faster with less code

Comment: If you have 5 lines, you want 5 different lists? In your expected output, you list only 2 lists. There should be 5 - one for each of the 5 lines you show as inputs, correct? Also, why does both your list have `0101062000` as the 3rd item? Shouldn't the list from 00:23:15 have `0101108700` as the 3rd item? Are you OK with having 1 dictionary variable that contains 4000 lists?

Comment: Maybe I will try to use Pandas, but a nice lady really nailed my question. cheers to her.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there! The only thing left - is to iterate through all the rows and split them into lists:

```
rows = open("data.txt").readlines() 
rows = [row.split("#") for row in rows]
print(rows)
```

Output:

```
[['2023-07-01 00:05:12', '11111111111', '0101107200', '0055013565', '3', '724020'], ['2023-07-01 00:23:15', '22222222222', '0101108700', '0099000002', '0', '724020'], ['2023-07-01 00:26:57', '33333333333', '0101062000', '0099000029', '0', '724020'], ['2023-07-01 01:33:31', '44444444444', '0101107100', '0055013566', '3', '724020'], ['2023-07-01 01:37:15', '55555555555', '0101107100', '0055013566', '3', '724020']]
```

By the way, avoid naming variables with reserved names like `list`. Renamed `List` to `rows` here.

Comment: U are the bossss, now I am ready to automate a bunch of work, happy day